# C# ContextMenu Opening() event

Tags: c#, event-handling, contextmenu

I am porting a Windows Forms GUI made contextmenustrip into contextmenu code in a class.
(I am making a "self containing MS Chart class", so each chart I make can get its own contextmenu.)

Here is a code sample, with two menuitems and a dividing bar:

```
    ContextMenu mymenustrip = new ContextMenu();
    zoomOutToolStripMenuItem = new MenuItem("Zoom Out", 
      new EventHandler(chart_ToolStripMenuItem_zoomOutClick));
    separator1ToolStripMenuItem = new MenuItem("-");
    mymenustrip.MenuItems.Add(zoomOutToolStripMenuItem);
```

and the menus do work, easily copied from the GUIs event logic. And there's also a lot of online examples helping on this. *But how do I catch the menu's Opening() event?*
The original Opening() event reformats the menu and I want to keep that functionality. 
I have fumbled with this:

```
mymenustrip.Popup += new EventHandler (chart_contextMenuStrip1_Opening)
...
```

but it is of course not sufficient. Here's the current error:
" Error CS0123  No overload for 'chart_contextMenuStrip1_Opening' matches delegate 'EventHandler' ". And this is the opening event, made by teh VS GUI:

```
private void chart_contextMenuStrip1_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
            if (zoomingNow)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }
...
}
```

Obviously I am missing something. But what?

Comment: You seem to be mixing up old school ContextMenu and MenuItems and new school ContextMenuStrips and ToolStripMenuItems.

Comment: Well, not really. Just keeping the variable names. I am aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you are using the default `EventHandler`, which expects a method with the signature `void methodname(object, EventArgs)`.

Your method however has a parameter of type `CancelEventArgs`.

You need to change the parameter type like this:

```
private void chart_contextMenuStrip1_Opening(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

If you need to use `CancelEventArgs` in your Function, you also need to use a Eventhandler that supports this type, e.g. `new EventHandler<CancelEventArgs>(yourMethod)`